# Formatting datatable's data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm currently working with a datatable which I'm populating not through an AJAX, so I believe I can't use the datasrc option. Is there any way I can format one of my columns before printing it? Like through a function or something. Your help is greatly appreciated. (By formatting I mean for example get the value from "constructionAmount" and adding a $ and some commas.)

```
$("#showDepreciationMontlhytable").DataTable({              
            destroy:true,
            responsive: true,
            autoWidth : true,
            searching: true, 
            data: transaction.transactionDetails,               
            columns:[
                    {"data": "idRealEstate"},
                    {"data": "name"},
                    {"data": "addressState"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.constructionAmount"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.depreciationPercentageYearly"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.monthsUse"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.usefulLifeMonths"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.amount"}
                    ]   ,       
            language: {
                url: datatablesSpanishUrl
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out an answer, there's the "render" option which lets you format the datta however it is needed.

```
$("#showDepreciationMontlhytable").DataTable({              
            destroy:true,
            responsive: true,
            autoWidth : true,
            searching: true, 
            data: transaction.transactionDetails,
            columns:[
                    {"data": "idRealEstate"},
                    {"data": "name"},
                    {"data": "addressState"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.constructionAmount",
                    "render" : function( data, type, full ) 
                        {
                            return currencyFormat(data,"$");                          
                        }
                    },
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.depreciationPercentageYearly"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.monthsUse"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.usefulLifeMonths"},
                    {"data": "depreciationDetail.amount",
                    "render" : function( data, type, full ) 
                        {
                            return currencyFormat(data,"$");                          
                        }
                    }
                    ]   ,       
            language: {
                url: datatablesSpanishUrl
            },
        }); 

function currencyFormat(n, currency) {
return currency + " " + n.toFixed(decimalRounding).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
```

}

Comment: Can't yet, it says I can't accept my own answers untill 2 days have passed.